# Taking value from string element and addition taken value with double-digit number

Tags: c, string, buffer

I want to take value from string and then addition taken value with double-digit number:

```
uint8_t buff[] = "Test123";
uint8_t result = 0;
result = buff[5] + 12;
```

If I try to addition taken value with single-digit(0,1,2,..,9) everything is ok, but if I want to addition taken value with double-digit number(10,11,12,13,...,99) I got for result ASCII code. How I can solve this problem? Casting was not worth it.

I expect for result 14 but I got 62. So program addition ASCII value of string with 12 but I want to addition integer value of buff[5] with 12 , I want this result = 12 + 2 = 14

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that single-digit is ok! It shouldn't be.... Anyway, you need to convert the string representation of the number to an integer type before adding things. Take a look at     http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtoul.3.html

Comment: What is your expected result? You are not doing arithmetics with numeric values but with characters representing a single digit.

Comment: `buff[5] + 12;` results in 62, right?

Comment: Yes, 62 in decimal, hex 0x3e. So I need to convert string to integer?

Comment: @subavet995 It's not clear what you want to do... maybe add some examples in your question. To start with.. what do you expect from `buff[5] + 12;` 62 or 14?

Comment: @subavet995 Please [edit] your question and add all information or clarification there instead of answering in comments.

Comment: @4386427 I expect 14, I want to operate with numbers so I want this equality result = 2 + 12 = 14

Comment: @subavet995 you get 62 because the decimal value of the ascii character '2' is 50, 50 + 12 = > 62. If you want the integer representation, then you can do ```result = (buff[5] - '0') + 12;``` or ```result = ((uint8_t)(buf[5] & 0x0F)) + 12;```

Comment: Thank you Vio, you solve my problem. I forget this trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get `62` is because you are adding the decimal value of the ASCII character `2` instead of the integer representation of it.

To convert the character to an integer, we would have to do this instead

```
result = (buf[5] - '0') + 12;               /* first way */

result = ((uint8_t)(buf[5] & 0x0F)) + 12;   /* second way */
```

First way: The ASCII decimal value of the character `2` is `50` and of the character `0` is `48` => `'2' - '0' = 2`

Second way: The hex values of the characters from `0` to `9` are `[0x30, 0x31, ..., 0x39]`. We can see that the first nibble corresponds to the integer representation of the character which means that we can toggle off the high-order nibble of its hex value.

Comment: The first is a good portable way - does not depend on ASCII - to extract a digit.  The 2nd approach relies on ASCII properties.  (and has an unnecessary cast)